# Retrieve scores of two friends above GKLocalPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center

I want to show a very small leaderboard snippet on my games front page, basically showing your score and the scores of two friends around you (above and below you're score).  I have read through the apple documentation and cannot see a way to do this unless I specify all friends and specify a huge range to ensure I get all the friends, which I can then filter.  It seems inefficient to retrieve this list especially as the user may be on mobile.  How can I achieve what I want without downloading the entire list of friends and then filtering?

Here is what I currently have (without filtering)

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
{
    leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeFriendsOnly;
    leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardRequest.category = @"HighScore";
    leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,100);
    [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        if (scores != nil)
        {
            GKScore* myScore = leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore;

            NSLog(@"Me: %@: %d",myScore.playerID, (int)myScore.value);

            // Process the score information - here I would filter
            for (GKScore* score in scores) 
            {
                NSLog(@"%@: %d",score.playerID, (int)score.value);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: If you want to display two friends that have the scores right below and above the user's one, you could try to specify the range depending on the currents player rank (-1 and +1).

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you.

> From Game Center Programming Guide: 
>       GKLeaderboard **range**: You can pick scores within a specific range. For example, the range [1,10] returns the best ten scores found by the query. 
>       GKScore **rank**: The position of the score in the results of a leaderboard search.

ps. I couldn't test it.
Best regards.

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
{
    GKScore* myScore = leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore;

    leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeFriendsOnly;
    leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
    leaderboardRequest.category = @"HighScore";
    leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(myScore.rank-1, myScore.rank+1);

    [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        else 
        {
            // ...
        }
    }];
}
```